# angular DOM created component append from html side not ts file

Tags: angular

i created a element and hold it inside the variable , here through ts we can append the element , but i want on html side at specific position , i want to render the element  like
[StackBlits example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pxlkn7?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

This way is not possible. A HTMLElement is only a object. So you cannot insert it to your view this way.

By the way: It's not a good way to create elements manually because change detection, rendering and so on.

But what you can do is to set a innerHTML:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  htmlcode!: SafeHtml;

  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.htmlcode = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("<button class='button-class'>test</button>");
  }
}
```

The DomSanitizer is needed to check the html code for secure. [DomSanitizer Angular Guide](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

Greetings, Flo